# Convert a CFG into CNF

Tags: context-free, normal-forms

I'm still new to `CFG and CNF` and have trouble sometimes understanding the concepts.

I'm trying to convert this CFG into Chomsky Normal Form:

```
G: S -> aSbS | bSaS | epsilon
```

I think the language generates all strings with same number of a and b, i.e. `{a^n b^n |n>-0}`.

But to convert it into CNF, I've finished adding a new start state and eliminating epsilon-productions:

```
S_0 -> S | epsilon
S -> aSbS | bSaS | aS | bS | a | b
```

Perhaps I need two non-terminals(variables) A -> a and B -> b :

```
S_0 -> S | epsilon
S -> ASBS | BSAS | AS | BS | a | b
A -> a
B -> b
```

I'm stuck here and really don't know what the next step should be. There seem to be no unit productions or useless symbols.

Comment: Why don't you follow the algorithm you've been given (or can be found in any textbook on the subject)?

Comment: @Raphael some textbooks and resources online all have different rules and I simply got confused.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/48267/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/33109077/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_normal_form#Converting_a_grammar_to_Chomsky_normal_form) has a good breakdown of how to convert to CNF.

Your first steps are correct, if incomplete: you should have the following:

```
S_0 -> S | epsilon
S -> ASBS | BSAS | AS | BS | A | B
A -> a
B -> b
```

(Notice the S rule.)

The next thing you need to do is decompose your `S` state(s) into multiple states, each with two or less nonterminals:

```
S -> T | W | AS | BS | A | B
T -> AU
U -> SV
V -> BS
W -> BX
X -> SY
Y -> AS
```

Does this get you unstuck?